# Web Map with OpelLayers, polar projection

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am quite new into the we map topic and quite frustrated. After reading lots of examples with different libraries etc I managed to get even more confused. So I will start with a trivial example. I provide here the trivial code to plot a web map using openlayers. My aim is to have a polar projection of the map.

html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Accessible Map</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="map.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map" ></div>
    <script>init();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
function init(){
  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
      attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
        collapsible: false
      })
    }),
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
    })
  });
}
```

This code while produce a map with a default Web Mercator projection (EPSG:3857)

According to https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/faq.html

in order to change the projection we need to register our desired one. So in my function I added:

```
var epsg3413 =  new ol.proj.Projection({  //NSIDC Sea Ice Polar Stereographic North
  code: "EPSG:3413",
  extent: [-4194304, 4194304, 4194304, -4194304],
  units: "m"
});  

var epsg4326 = ol.proj.get("EPSG:4326");
```

Then with the view method we can change the map projection so i added:

```
center: ol.proj.transform([85, 85], epsg4326, epsg3413),
projection: epsg3413
```

With the additions regarding the projection change the map is not working at all. Even a

```
console.log(ol.proj.transform([85, 85], epsg4326, epsg3413))
```

is returning the same point (85,85) which means the projection transformation is not even working. Is there an obvious mistake I am doing here? Please correct me also to this basic question: the ol.source.OSM() gets data from a tiled WMS server. By default the tiles are in web mercator projection. Can I plot them at all in polar stereographic or I should find a WMS server which be default provides tiles in polar projections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your projection definition is not correct. I can recommend to use [proj4j](http://proj4js.org/):

```
// projection definition (http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-nsidc-sea-ice-polar-stereographic-north/proj4js/)
proj4.defs('EPSG:3413', "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs");

var transformedCoordinate = ol.proj.transform([85,85], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3413');
// results in [415170.5793604837, 348369.4800170395]
```

Comment: Many thanks for the correct guidance. I just need to mention also for future users: Since I saw quite some examples, I followed their notation on the projection definition. Of course this requires that the projection code is already defined (or somehow known) to the ol.proj method which is definitely not the case. I think it does know 4-5 projections and the rest should be explicitly defined. Thanks again!